# VirtualizingStackPanel is working fine in ListView's ItemPanel. But not the simple StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-4.0

I just want to display Items in ListView like windows explorer (Large icons). For the same I used the below code.

```
    <ListView Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding MovieList}"  > 

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <!-- <VirtualizingStackPanel/> -->      <!-- Working Fine -->

                <StackPanel/>                           <!-- Items are not displayed -->
                                                        <!-- It must be wrap panel -->
                                                        <!-- OK, lets see with simple -->
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

In the above code, If I use VirtualizingStackPanel then the items are displayed fine, but one by one which I don't want. If I use StackPanel, the items are not dispalyed in screen, even the items are not added in StackPanel. I checked with Snoop tool.
I should use WrapPanel instread of StackPanel to list items, but lets see the simple StackPanel.

Why the items are not displayed in StackPanel?
Basically I want list the items like WindowExplorer large icon view.

I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: But WrapPanel does almost exactly was explorer is showing.

Comment: Yes @OliverWeichhold, I tried like the following also, but not working.

`code`
 <ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <Wrappanel/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemsPanel>
`code`

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: I need to list items like wrap panel in a list view. So I just used ItemsPanel property of listview. I simply tried with WrapPanel inside the ItemsPanelTemplate, but items are not displayed in list view.
but If I use VirtualizingStackPanel inside the ItemsPanelTemplate then the items are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing in my code and it's working fine. Virtualization works as long as size of the ItemsControl's viewport is restricted. 
just try replacing the code given below:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Director}" FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```